# Understanding Clean Architecture

Tags: clean-architecture

Below is my understanding of the projects involved .However my confusion comes from the difference between Application/Core/Domain . Is it also correct to say  Core = Application + Domain because i have come across some projects without core?

**Api**

Accepts input in the form of http requests over the network (e.g., GET/POST/etc.) and returns its output as content formatted as JSON/HTML/XML, etc.

**Application**

Contains business logic and types. (Implements Cases)

**Core**

Our External Interfaces get defined here. The code in this layer is mostly pure C# - no network connections, databases, etc. allowed. Interfaces represent those dependencies, and their implementations get injected into our use cases

**Infrastructure**

In here, we define data entities, database access , integrations with external services. This project/layer contains the physical implementation of the interfaces defined in our core project.

Comment: What is your source for the above incorrect summary? I would advise to do some more research and start with Uncle Bob's original blog post.

Comment: This blog might help you:
https://pusher.com/tutorials/clean-architecture-introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fine understanding... of Onion Architecture.

While Clean Architecture has much the same flavor, the names you’re using come from Onion, not Clean.

Read up on both architectures. Let us know if you still have questions we haven’t already answered.